# Is the inverse of bijective continuous functions always continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, inverse

Let $X,~Y$ be two metric spaces, $E\subseteq X$, $f:E\to Y$. I have a question that is lingering in my mind long. If $f$ is continuous and one-to-one, then does $f^{-1}:f(E)\to E$ continuous? I think the answer is true, is it? Is there counterexample? However, I read several books, some of them just prove that if $E$ is compact, then it is so. Why don't they more generally discuss it?

PS: The definition of continuity is: $f:E\to Y$ is called continuous iff the preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $E$ for all open set $U$ in $Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true in general. Just take the identity from $\mathbb R$ endowed with the discrete metric into $\mathbb R$ endowed with the usual metric. It is continuous, but its inverse isn't.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any counterexample from  $(\Bbb R^n,~d_{\ell^2})$  to  $(\Bbb R^m,~d_{\ell^2})$? Is it possible to find one? I roughly guess that maybe in such "good enough space" it is true?

Comment: @Eric No, by [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).

Comment: @Eric But there **are** counterexamples with subspaces of $\mathbb R$ endowed with the usual metric.

Comment: Wow!! I haven't heard about this!! So indeed, let me check if I understand correctly: let $E\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ be open and $f:E\to \Bbb R^m$ be injective continuous function, then $f$ must be a *homeomorphism* (namely $f^{-1}$ must be continous). Why does such theorem not appear in traditional real analysis books? Is it because the proof requires the materials beyond the scope?

Comment: @Eric I suppose so. It takes some amount of Topology to prove it.

Comment: I just see your second comment. Well, the wikipedia doesn't say it clearly. What does you mean "there are counterexamples with subspaces of $\Bbb R$ endowed with the usual metric"? Do you mean when $E$ is too bad?

Comment: @Eric There are examples of continuous functios $f\colon A\longrightarrow B$, where $A,B\subset\mathbb R$ endowed with its usual distance, such that $f^{-1}$ is discontinuous.